# Searchkick boost_by_distance gives undefined method `reverse'

Tags: searchkick

What am I missing here? I simply copy paste the example on https://github.com/ankane/searchkick to the console and I get an error.

2.2.2 :001 > User.search "jim", boost_by_distance: {field: :location, origin: {lat: 37, lon: -122}}
NoMethodError: undefined method `reverse' for {:lat=>37, :lon=>-122}:Hash

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest version of Searchkick (1.1.1).

Comment: My bad, this is a bug. Fixed on master.

Comment: Is there a difference between boost_by_distance and sorting by distance as I finally did? Is there an advantage? or is it basically the same command?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to sort the results by distance. Ended up using this query instead:

```
order: {_geo_distance: {coordinates: "#{find_coordinates[1]},#{find_coordinates[0]}", order: "asc", unit: "mi"} }
```

While I grab the coordinates from the ip with Geocoder:

```
def find_coordinates
  Geocoder.coordinates(request.remote_ip)
end
```